# Can you restrict Shoreditch from injecting CSS on Public pages with CiviCRM content?

Tags: drupal, css, theme, shoreditch

As the title says - can you restrict Shoreditch from injecting CSS on Public pages with CiviCRM content?

For example - do a fresh install of Drupal, CiviCRM and Shoreditch - choose any public theme - create any public facing CiviCRM page (event, contribution, etc) - go to that public page - shoreditch will inject much of its CSS on the page. Fonts, body backgrounds, etc.

Whats the easiest way to restrict shoreditch from injecting itself on public pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a core issue (not specific to Shoreditch) and there is an issue with some discussion related to it here:

- https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/378

To tag on to your specific point about Shoreditch's CSS, I have found this to be problematic for the display reasons you mention (conflicts with CSS from the front end theme) but also for performance reasons. On one site I found Google Page Speed Insights showed a very low mobile score (2%) with Shoreditch enabled, and it jumped to a more normal level (87%) as soon as I disabled the Shoreditch CSS.